# ymax to count values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a geom_linerange plot where ymax is a count of non-numerical values that appear in my data. The x axis needs to show categories available in the data and the y axis would be a count of how many times they appear in the data. Similar to geom_bar but instead of bars I need vertical lines.

The data is a line by line dataset showing employees in one column and categories they belong to in the other column.

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = Category)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ???))
```

The above works if I fix `ymax = 1000` and add `stat = "count"` but I struggle to make it work with `ymax =` count of values. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a 1 to your dataset and use `stat_summary()`

```r
df <-
  mpg %>% 
  mutate(n = 1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = n)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "linerange", ymin = 0, fun.ymax = "sum")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest/clearest to summarise your data first - to have a column with count.

Here is an example using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
   mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
         summarise(n = n()) %>%
        ggplot( aes(x = as.factor(cyl))) +
      geom_linerange(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = n))
```